# Properly places try and catches

Tags: java, multithreading, ioexception

I have a problem with proper use of try and catch statement.

Previously I had all this code in main method and it worked, but when I wanted to put it into separated thread problem appeared.

Previously I used' throws `IOException`, but in class which implements `Runnable` I cant just use `throws IOException` because there is an error.
I would like to get some advice, how to make this code work again but in thread.

I would appreciate all of the advice connected with making my code better.

```
public void run() { 
        File file= new File("Towar.txt");
      Scanner sc;
      BufferedReader br;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


        String line;
        int count=0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            line = br.readLine();
            if (line==null)break;

            int space = line.indexOf(" ");

            int id_towaru = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, space));
            double waga = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(space));
            Towar tow= new Towar(id_towaru,waga);
            count++;
            if (count%200==0)System.out.println("Created: "+ count + " objects");

        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: Wrap it with `try`/`catch`, what's the problem?

Comment: Please show us your attempt to use try/catch. Else how can we tell what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: when i wrap automatically with try-catch, there is problem with non initialized variables

Comment: @jawjaw not here, edit the question please.

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialize Scanner variable sc to null before the try / catch. Error gone.
2. Don't try to read a file with both a Scanner **and** a BufferedReader at the same time, but instead use one or the other.

---

```
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // exit program here?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i used " while (sc.hasNextLine())" because if i used br.readline()!= null, i read only half of the lines from the File.

Comment: @jawjaw: then you're doing something else wrong. You've got a bug and the solution is to find and fix the bug, not use some fragile kludge as you're doing.

Comment: @jawjaw If you are using `sc.hasNextX()`, the correct way to get X is to call `sc.nextX()`, for whatever X is. Since you are using `sc.hasNextLine()`, you should be using `sc.nextLine()` to read the next line.

Answer (score 1):

While @HovercraftFullOfEels already gave you an answer, I want to explain why you are getting this error.

Java requires that a variable should be assigned before it's used. See  [Chapter 16. Definite Assignment - 16.2.15. try Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.15):

> V is *definitely assigned* before a `catch` block iff V is definitely assigned before the `try` block.

... earlier in the [same chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is caused by the fact that a runnable is meant to be called asynchronously, so there is nothing "waiting" for it, and it also cannot have a return value.

depending on the rest of your application, and how this is being called, how many things in parallel are called etc, you have two main options:

1.) if the thing that starts the thread that runs this runnable doesn't really care about the result, you could just do the try catch inside the run() method. it would be then up to the catch block to take the appropriate action:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // do some stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // write some kind of error log
    }
}
```

2.) another way to do the same thing would be to do use a "Callable" instead of a "Runnable". a Callable can be scheduled pretty much like a Runnable, but it can throw exceptions, and it can have a return value.

```
public MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    public String call() throws Exception {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

now, if you use this approach, you will need some kind of Excutor, and submit the callable for execution. this will then return a

```
Future<String>
```

on which you can call a variety of get() methods that will throw exceptions (if your code throws an exception OR you get a timeout), or ot will return the actual return value.

a simple exaple:

http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example

Answer (score 0):

This is what your new method should look like. The following code will catch the exception in the correct places, and will also close all of your streams in order to prevent a resource leak.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        File file = new File("Towar.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;

            int space = line.indexOf(" ");

            int id_towaru = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, space));
            double waga = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(space));
            Towar tow= new Towar(id_towaru,waga);
            count++;
            if (count % 200 == 0)
                System.out.println("Created: " + count + " objects");

        }
        sc.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use try catch places there thing can fail like in this line:

```
try{
int id_towaru = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, space));
}
catch(Exception e){
//something you want this part to do, eks:
System.out.println("did not find Integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After the Exception has occurred, your code happily continues to parse the input file. This doesn't make sense, as the file does not exist, so parsing should be skipped. There are two ways to do this:

1. Add a `return` after `e.printStackTrace();`. This will skip the rest of the body of the method
2. Wrap the entire parsing code in the `try/catch` statement by moving the `catch` block below the `while` statement in your code.

---

```
File file= new File("Towar.txt");
Scanner sc;
BufferedReader br;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(file);
    br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    int count=0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line==null)break;

        int space = line.indexOf(" ");

        int id_towaru = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, space));
        double waga = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(space));
        Towar tow= new Towar(id_towaru,waga);
        count++;
        if (count%200==0)System.out.println("Created: "+ count + " objects");
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

While the first solution is probably nicer to look at (because it avoids excessive indentation), the second one might be easier to understand.